# which linker does macOS Mojave use

Tags: macos, linker

The command `clang -fuse-ld=bfd` returns error, saying invalid linker name in argument `-fuse-ld=bfd`.

I have tried `bfd`, `lld` and `ld`. It seems that only `ld` is correct.

But, in my mind, `ld` is the general term for the linker and does not refer to a specific linker (`ld.bfd` on Linux).

So I wonder that which linker does macOS actually use?

Answer (score 3):

macOS uses Apple's own linker, `ld64`. The source is available [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-409.12/).